# List all users who have a gold badge

Tags: support, badges, users

Is there any way to list all the users who have any Gold badge, not by badge like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal), but any type of badge, like **Great Question**, **Famous Question**, **Gold badge in Java**, **Gold badge in Discussion**, ...

Comment: Do any of these queries do what you need? http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=gold+badges

Comment: Yes i think i need something like this, you link really helped me, so now i will make my own query, thank you @RoryAlsop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query to do that. I just [made one](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/607027/users-with-gold-badges) for you:

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT u.Id AS [User Link],
  MAX(b.Name) AS 'One of the gold badges they have',
  COUNT(*) AS 'Number of gold badges'
  FROM Users AS u
  INNER JOIN Badges AS b
    ON b.UserId = u.Id
  WHERE b.Class = 1
  GROUP BY u.Id
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/fork/607027) and experiment.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i think this SEDE query also do what i search for http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/567586/recent-gold-badges-earned :)

Comment: Yes, but users may appear multiple times in that list.

Comment: i see thank you then soo much :)

Comment: is there any way to query for a specific tag? Like get the list of all users who have bronze medal for the Java tag?

Comment: Yes, if you [fork](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/fork/607027/) the query, you can add an extra condition to the `WHERE` and filter on `b.Name`. Or just check the [bronze Java tag badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/276/java) itself; there's no need to pull this data from SEDE when it's available *real-time*.